# css animation working in chrome but not firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, css-animations

The following CSS works in Chrome 35 but does not work in Firefox 30:

```
@-webkit-keyframes redpulse {
    from { background-color: #FFAAA3; }
    to { background-color: red; }
}

@-moz-keyframes redpulse {
    from { background-color: #FFAAA3; }
    to { background-color: red; }
}

@keyframes redpulse {
    from { background-color: #FFAAA3; }
    to { background-color: red; }
}

.red-pulse {
    -webkit-animation: redpulse 400ms 0 1 alternate;
    -moz-animation: redpulse 400ms 0 1 alternate;
    animation: redpulse 400ms 0 1 alternate;
}
```

Is there some firefox specific pitfall that I'm falling into?

Edit Solution:

Thanks for the quick response.  The issue turned to be that using !important on the base CSS has different implementations on Chrome and Firefox.

Chrome will override !important CSS with animation CSS, Firefox will not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have too many values in you rule or it is miswritten.

`animation: redpulse 400ms 0s 1 alternate;/* should work much better*/`

**time values need units** .

Firefox doesnt need the prefix anymore. **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wClym)**
test this and :

```
@keyframes redpulse {
    to { background-color: red; }
}

html {
    animation: redpulse 400ms   alternate;/* or next to keep pulsing*/
  animation: redpulse 400ms   alternate infinite;
  background-color: #FFAAA3;
}
```